# InvalidCastException in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq

I used the LINQ to SQL code generator to generate a simple data context that reads GUIDs from a SQL Server table, and I access the read GUIDs by using a simple LINQ call such as the following:

```
dataContext.MyTable.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID.Equals(id))
```

For the most part, this call works well, but I infrequently get an error such as the following error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type '<>c__DisplayClass356' to type 'System.Func`1[System.Guid]'
```

Could anyone please suggest what might cause this error and why this error does not happen every time?

Thank you.

Comment: The error doesn't correspond with the query you've shown us. The error is occurring somewhere else. It's describing a function which only returns a `Guid`. Your function takes an object and returns a `bool`.

Comment: What is the value of `id` here? And what are you assigning the result of the query to?

Comment: How did you get the value of id

Comment: Hi.  Thank you for your responses.  Following is the full code:

        internal MyTable Fetch(Guid id)
        {
            using (MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext(connectionString))
            {
                return db.MyTable.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID.Equals(id));
            }
        }

Comment: Have you try this dataContext.MyTable.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID.ToString() == id.ToString());

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
dataContext.MyTable.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID.ToString() == id.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently class `MyTable` has a property `ID` of type `System.Guid`.

You don't specify the type of `id`. Because of your error report it is not a `Guid`. As it quite often works, I assume it is something that can easily be parsed to a `Guid`, like a string. Could it be that sometimes the string id does not represent a proper `Guid`?

The solution others gave does not work:

```
var myTable = dataContext.MyTable.First(); // assume not empty
Guid myGuid = myTable.ID;                  // assume not empty
string id = myGuid.ToString("X");

// The solution suggested by others does not find the element:
Guid foundGuid = dataContext.MyTable.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID.ToString() == id.ToString());
```

Reason: myGuid.ToString() results in a different string, and although id is a good string representation of myGuid, it is unequal to myGuid.ToString()

The following code will certainly find the element:

```
Guid idGuid = Guid.Parse(id);
Debug.Assert(myGuid.Equals(idGuid);
Guid foundGuid = dataContext.MyTable.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID.Equals(idGuid));
```

If you are not certain that id is a proper Guid, Use `Guid.TryParse`, instead of `Guid.Parse` If it doesn't even parse to a proper guid, don't bother to start your linq statement, because you are certain that it is not in MyTable